# Failed to generate code for the service reference on a webservice

Tags: asp.net, soap

EgoPay's website  has a WebService that i'm trying to work with, But there is a problem when i add it to my Asp.Net project( I added it through "Add Service Reference" option)  after building solution i have got an error :

`Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'ServiceReference1'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details.`

and i have got 3 Warning   :

> **1-** Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
>   Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: The datatype 'schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is missing.
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='www.egopay.com/api/soap']/wsdl:portType[@name='API_EgoPay_SoapPort']
>
> **2-** Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
>   Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
>   XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='www.egopay.com/api/soap']/wsdl:binding[@name='API_EgoPay_SoapBinding']
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='www.egopay.com/api/soap']/wsdl:service[@name='API_EgoPay_SoapService']/wsdl:port[@name='API_EgoPay_SoapPort']
>
> **3-** Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
>   Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
>   XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='www.egopay.com/api/soap']/wsdl:portType[@name='API_EgoPay_SoapPort']
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='https://www.egopay.com/api/soap']/wsdl:binding[@name='API_EgoPay_SoapBinding']

**the webservice address is** : https://www.egopay.com/api/soap?wsdl

i searched in the net for this error and most of answers were "uncheck Reused types in referenced assemblies" but it did'nt work to me.

i'll be thankfull if anyone help me or anyone could test this webservice in asp.net and tell me the result.